# How to add minimize and maximize icon for the Dialog in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am beginner with PyQt5 .I have develop some application in dialog but later i noticed there is no minimize and maximize icon in dialog by default.How can i get these one in dialog box.
Any suggestion will be helpful.Thanks in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'makebeautiful.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_ZValue(object):
    def setupUi(self, ZValue):
        ZValue.setObjectName("ZValue")
        ZValue.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ZValue)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 131, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ZValue)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 150, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(ZValue)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ZValue)

    def retranslateUi(self, ZValue):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ZValue.setWindowTitle(_translate("ZValue", "Copy Z Cordinate"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("ZValue", "Cofirm"))



import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from  makebeautiful import *
class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_ZValue()
        # self.ui.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)
        # self.ui.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dispmessage)
        self.show()
    def dispmessage(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("Clicked")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a maximize and minimize button for a `QDialog`, you need to set the window flags `Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint`and `Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint`, respectively, e.g.

```
dialog.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)
dialog.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Heike for reply.While i was using above code 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'setWindowFlag error is generating .I have used with  dialog object (self.ui.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True) .

Comment: Does `self.ui` inherit from `QDialog`? If you add your code to your post people are better able to answer you question.

Comment: sorry for late posting. I just tried  but it is showing error.The added code is now commented.

Comment: @Devenepali Only use `self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)` and `self.etWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)` after `self.ui.setupUi(self)`. ui is not a widget, it is a class that fills a widget, I recommend you read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code